# Pester test for installing SCCM OS Patches

Tags: powershell, pester

I have a working PowerShell script for installing any patches currently showing as available to be installed in the SCCM Client but I have found no way of building a pester test to verify that the script works as expected without actually having a patch to install.

Can there be a dummy patch created somehow, installed, tested, and then uninstalled at the end of the pester test?  I have no idea if that is even possible.

Script for installing available patches:

```
Function Install-SCCMAvailablePatches {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    [Parameter( 
      Mandatory = $False,
      ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $True,
      HelpMessage = "Reboot Server if needed? Default: True")]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string]
    $Reboot = $True
  )

  begin {
    Write-Verbose "Install-SCCMAvailablePatches: Started"
  }

  process {
    try {  ([wmiclass]'ROOT\ccm\ClientSDK:CCM_SoftwareUpdatesManager').InstallUpdates([System.Management.ManagementObject[]] (Get-WmiObject -Query 'SELECT * FROM CCM_SoftwareUpdate' -namespace 'ROOT\ccm\ClientSDK')) 
        while (Not((Get-WmiObject -Namespace 'ROOT\ccm\ClientSDK' -Class 'CCM_ClientUtilities' -list).DetermineIfRebootPending().RebootPending)) {
            $Time = (get-date).ToShortTimeString()
            Write-Verbose "Still Patching @ $Time"
            Start-Sleep -s 60 }
        if ($Reboot -eq $True) {
            if ((Get-WmiObject -Namespace 'ROOT\ccm\ClientSDK' -Class 'CCM_ClientUtilities' -list).DetermineIfRebootPending().RebootPending) {
               (Get-WmiObject -Namespace 'ROOT\ccm\ClientSDK' -Class 'CCM_ClientUtilities' -list).RestartComputer()
            }      
        }
    }
    catch {
      Write-Error -Message "Something went wrong with Install-SCCMAvailablePatches."
    }
  }

  end {
    Write-Verbose "Install-SCCMAvailablePatches: Completed"
  }      
} #End Install-SCCMAvailablePatches
```

Comment: You can use mocks, but with all your WMI calls, that may be difficult.

Comment: Understanding mocking is key to doing complex tests with Pester.  One school of thought is that if your code is too complex, Pester will help you simplify it in order to be able to write tests for it.  The other school of thought is to have Pester test a success and failed case, and make sure your script outputs what you're expecting.  You can walk through each if statement mocking a $True or $False and measure the output of the rest of your script.

Answer (score 0):

You should re-write your function to open it up for testing in the first place.  `Pester` encourages Test-Driven-Development, meaning you define your inputs, define your outputs, write tests to ensure those results, then write the code.

```
Function Install-SCCMAvailablePatches
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [ValidateScript({
            <# Test conditions #>
        })]
        [System.Management.ManagementObject]$UpdateManager,
        [Switch]$Reboot
    )

    Begin
    {
        Write-Verbose "Install-SCCMAvailablePatches: Started"
    }

    Process
    {
        Try
        {
            $UpdateManager.InstallUpdates(
                @(Get-WmiObject -Query 'SELECT * FROM CCM_SoftwareUpdate' -Namespace 'ROOT\ccm\ClientSDK')
            )

            $Client = Get-WmiObject -Namespace 'ROOT\ccm\ClientSDK' -Class 'CCM_ClientUtilities'
            While (-not $Client.DetermineIfRebootPending().RebootPending)
            {
                Write-Verbose (Get-Date -UFormat 'Still patching @ %H:%M')
                Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
            }

            If ($Reboot -and $Client.DetermineIfRebootPending().RebootPending)
            {
                $Client.RestartComputer()
            }
        }
        Catch
        {
            Write-Error -Message "Something went wrong with Install-SCCMAvailablePatches."
        }
    }  

    End
    {
        Write-Verbose "Install-SCCMAvailablePatches: Completed"
    }      
}
```

Now, you can mock the wmi object passed as a parameter with your own object/properties in your Pester tests.

Comment: I have never done mocking before and am unsure how to mock my code for use with pester.  I want to be able to run this code as a test on a server that has no patches available to install yet it still will test the code as if it did install any available patches along with a mock reboot.  As of right now I do not have a pester test built for this code as I didn't know where to start in regards to mocking.  Do you mock the actual script and then have peter call the mocked script?

Comment: @Keith Mocks are basically just self-defined functions so you'd do something like `Mock Get-WmiObject { Return $True }` but obviously you'd define your own implementation.  For the purpose of testing, they replace that function call (which is usually a well-known cmdlet)

Comment: ok, so I have started researching how to use mocking but I attempted to use your code to just accomplish my original task and it keeps giving me an error. What value should be getting passed to the $UpdateManager.